# Using Lazy Loading when related entities reside within the same aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

From  [DDD: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) ( pg. 177 ):

> The need to update Delivery History when adding a Handling Event gets
>   the Cargo AGGREGATE involved in the transaction.

a) Further down the page author does propose an alternative solution, but still - isn't author in above excerpt essentially proposing that we'd implement an *association* by having `DeliveryHistory.Events` property query a database ( via *repository* ) each time this *property* gets accessed?

b) Since implementation "proposed" by author is almost identical to how *lazy loading* is implemented ( with an exception that *lazy loading* only queries for data the first time we need it and then caches it ), I'll also ask the following:

Many are against *lazy loading* in general, but regardless, I assume that we should never use lazy loading if *related entities* reside within the *same aggregate*, since such an *association* is expressed with *object reference*, which is implemented when we require a *transactional integrity*?

Reason being that this *integrity* may be compromised if *related data* is never accessed ( and as such is never retrieved ), since *invariants* can't be enforced properly when *aggregate* is modified?

**UPDATE:**

a)

> The DeliveryHistory.Events collection can be loaded when the
>   DeliveryHistory entity is loaded by the repository. It can also be
>   loaded via lazy loading in which case an ORM injects a collection
>   proxy which when iterated calls the database.

But isn't author proposing a third option, which is to query for *events* each time `DeliveryHistory.Events` is accessed ( or perhaps each time `DeliveryHistory.GetEvents()` is called )?

b)

> It is similar to lazy loading however the important difference is that
>   resorting to a repository query allows the omission of the Events
>   property in the object model. This reduces the "footprint" of the
>   DeliveryHistory entity.

I - I'm assuming that by "*being similar to lazy loading*" you're referring to a design where *events* are retrieved from the db each time they are requested?!

II - Anyways, if we omit the `DeliveryHistory.Events` property ( and presumably don't define as an alternative  a `DeliveryHistory.GetEvents()`), how then do we implement a design proposed by author ( as noted in my original post, I'm aware that further down the page author did propose a better alternative )?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The `DeliveryHistory.Events` collection can be loaded when the DeliveryHistory entity is loaded by the repository. It can also be loaded via lazy loading in which case an ORM injects a collection proxy which when iterated calls the database.

b) It is similar to lazy loading however the important difference is that resorting to a repository query allows the omission of the Events property in the object model. This reduces the "footprint" of the `DeliveryHistory` entity.

The problem with lazy loading is not that data may never be accessed, it is that accessing a lazy loaded property for the first time will result in a database call and you have to make sure that the connection is still alive. In a sense, this can compromise the integrity of the aggregate which should be considered a whole.

**UPDATE**

a) Either way the net result is the same. I'm not sure if creating a proxy collection was a technique utilized when the book was written (2003).

b1) Yes, they are similar in that the events aren't loaded together with the DeliveryHistory entity, but only on demand.

b2) Instead of an events property on the DeliveryHistory entity, the events would be accessed by calling a repository. The repository itself would be called by the surrounding application service. It would retrieve the events and pass them to places that needed them. Or if the use case is adding events, the application service would call the repository to persist the event.

Comment: "The problem with lazy loading ... you have to make sure that the connection is still alive. In a sense, this can compromise the integrity of the aggregate which should be considered a whole."
And for the same reason we also shouldn't implement a design where each time DeliveryHistory.Events is accessed, a DB query would be performed? In other words, there's a chance a connection to DB would be broken and as such integrity of the aggregate would be compromised  ( since aggregate conceptually couldn't be considered as being whole  )?

Comment: Lazy loading would be the design wherein once Events is accessed the DB is called (even though it is only called once). And yes, the DB connection could be broken since at the time the collection is being loaded, the entity could be in a different context than at the time it was originally loaded from repo.

Comment: "Lazy loading would be the design wherein once Events is accessed the DB is called (even though it is only called once).2 If I understand you correctly, conceptually the design is still considered as lazy loading, even though DeliveryHistory.Events property retrieves related events each time it gets accessed?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would qualify as lazy loading in the traditional sense. Perhaps delayed loading would be more appropriate. Lazy is usually associated with delayed loading that is cached after the first time.